# How to tell my boss that I hate some of the work?

Tags: management

My manager is very supportive but sometimes he gives me some User Acceptance Testing (UAT) testing to do which I hate doing, it’s related to my job description but i just hate that part so much!

What should I say or do?

Comment: What do you expect to gain by telling your boss that you hate your assigned work?

Comment: You are paid to do the work, not enjoy it.

Comment: I understand your point of view but im not saying I won’t do it, im saying I dislike it and it’s giving me a hard time

Comment: Could you provide some information anout what makes you dislike said task? I assume that asking your manager for potential improvements might be more fruitful.

Comment: *What should I say or do?* is not well suited for this site.  Try being specific with what you are interested in getting help with.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You see how employment works is that they exchange something you want (money) for something they want (work) and if this is something that's part of your job description then at it's most basic **you already agreed to that trade.**

Now you've got a bit of buyers remorse and you want to change the deal, the good news is that sometimes you can do this - but the bad news is it's generally it's going to need something more than one party not liking providing something in order to get that changed. Otherwise they could just turn around and point out that they hate having to pay you money and aren't going to do that any more.

You need to make a new deal that gives both parties something they want - So if you want to get away from doing the UAT work you're going to have to offer them something else that they want *instead* - and since you already have a "deal" with them you're probably going to have to offer them something they want/need more than you doing the UAT work, otherwise they're probably going to decline.

So don't just go to your manager and tell them you hate doing UAT and you'd rather not do that any more - go to them and say you think you will be more valuable to them if you spend that time doing X,Y, and Z instead. And you need to be prepared to justify why you doing that is going to benefit your employer.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than "hate", try a more positive spin on things:

> I am happy working on <thing 1> and <thing 2>, but I'd don't enjoy <other thing> so much because <reason>. Would it be possible for us to try <solution> which would mean that <reason> gets better?

The point is here rather than just saying "no", you're actually trying to make things better - *why* do you dislike UAT work, and what could be done about it so that it was less bad?

Comment: Thanks but would that approach affect my relationship with my boss?

Comment: We can't tell you that, we know virtually nothing about you and even less about your boss.